# RemoveDuplicates only deletes if the positions are 1 and 2

Tags: c++

This is a continuation [Removing duplicates from a DoublyLinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126160/removing-duplicates-from-a-doublylinkedlist-c/16126231?noredirect=1#comment23034655_16126231).  Anyway, I have gotten so far as to remove the duplicates but it only removes a duplicate if the positions are one or two.  Can anybody see anything that would make this happen.  Here is he function:

```
void RemoveDuplicates(DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype> m_itr, string searchByFirstName, string searchBySecondName)
{
    for (m_itr.Start(); m_itr.Valid(); m_itr.Forth())
        {
            if ((m_itr.Item().getFirstName() == searchByFirstName )&& (m_itr.Item().getSecondName() == searchBySecondName))
            {
                DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype> toDelete = m_itr; 
                m_itr.Forth(); 
                Remove(toDelete);
            }   
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `break` after the first iteration of the loop so it'll only do one iteration.

Comment: If i dont do that it, after the first time i remove the duplicate, which works it will began deleting both of the objects.

Comment: I've no idea what you just said

Comment: Aswell, it only removes two if they are not beside each other in the list.

Comment: lol its very glitcy, i removed the break and like i said above, it will delete both the duplicate and the one i want to keep if they arent beside each other in the list.